# Relational calculus databases

Tags: relational-database, relational, tuple-relational-calculus

I have a schema that looks like this:
Student (sid, name, age, department)
Course(cid, name)
Enrollment(sid, cid, term, grade)

Using relational calculus, find the names of the students who took all courses.
What I have now looks like this:

{t | ∃ s ∈ Student (t.name = s.name ^ ∃ e ∈ Enrollment(s.sid = e.sid 
^ ∀ c ∈ C (c.cid = e.cid)))  }

Can someone tell me if this is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't correct or well formed.  Logical conjunction doesn't range over quantifiers (i.e. you can't write ^ ∀) and even if it did, your expression would try to find all course ids in a single enrollment of a single student.

The correct answer could be stated in English: find all students where there doesn't exist a course for which the student doesn't have an enrollment.

Comment: "you can't write ^ ∀" There's no syntax problem evident, the syntax seems to have `wff ^ wff` a wff & `∀ tuple ∈ base (wff)` a wff.